# Inconsistent accessibility after Ninject Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I just added Ninject dependency injection into my code, and after righting the constructor I am getting the following error on my Constructor:

```
Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Final.Models.IUserRepo' is less accessible than method 'Final.Controllers.HomeController.HomeController(Final.Models.IUserRepo)'    C:\Users\Ali\Documents\Final\Final\Controllers\HomeController.cs    17  16  Final
```

Following is my **HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    IUserRepo repo;

    public HomeController(IUserRepo u)
    {
        u = repo;
    }
}
```

Here is my interface:

```
namespace Final.Models
{
    interface IUserRepo
    {
        void save(User u);
    }
}
```

I tried changing all the methods to public but nothing worked.

Comment: I have edited your question down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as your question didn't follow the Minimal principle. Please keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: I assume you mean `repo = u`, not `u = repo;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a public interface. That's what the error message is telling you. You can't use it as a parameter on a public method (the constructor) if the interface is private. Otherwise, how could one construct a `HomeController`?

```
namespace Final.Models
{
    public interface IUserRepo
    {
        void save(User u);
    }
}
```

Also, you should modify your code to follow standard C# naming conventions. Don't use abbreviation, PascalCase your method names.

```
namespace Final.Models
{
    public interface IUserRepo
    {
        void Save(User uuser);
    }
}
```